# how to modify S3 copy source when key is a list of files

Tags: amazon-s3, copy

I was trying to copy files from one folder to another folder within a bucket. But the copy source key should be multiple files. The result path is a list with multiple paths. I tried the below two ways, but neither worked.

```
           for i in range(0,len(resultpath)):
                copy_source = {
                    'Bucket': bucketname,
                    'Key': resultpath[i]  #not sure if a list is OK
                }


            copy_source = {
                'Bucket': bucketname,
                'Key': {
                    'Objects':resultpath
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `copy_object()` command will only copy one object at a time.